# One row repeating multiple times in spring boot Jpa .findall() response restfull api

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, web-services

I have an issue when I fetch data from my database with jpaReposeitory from category table which has a foriegn key userId in it. relationship of oneToMany, data is coming almost fine but it repeats itself multiple times. here are some images :
[categoryServiceImpl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBiKf.png)

[Category Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2htXT.png)

[json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5CjQ.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqquR.png)

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to bidirectional relationship.Try using @JsonBackReference  in category class

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional= false)
@JsonBackReference
private User users;
```

Comment: Did you try like above code.Remove the @JoinColumn annotation

Comment: it worked for me when i change it to FetchType.EAGER